# how to calculate stock with jquery

Tags: jquery

I do not speak English well. I have a big problem because I have no knowledge of jquery. I want to develop a calculation of stock like this:

```
<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>producto</th>
        <th>entry</th>
        <th>exit</th>
        <th>stock</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr><td class="opening balance">10</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="info">TP031</td>
        <td class="entry">4</td>
        <td class="exit">0</td>

        <td class="stock">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="info">SI0352</td>
        <td id="entry">0</td>
        <td class="exit">3</td>

        <td class="stock">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="info">MP4012</td>
        <td class="entry">0</td>
        <td class="exit">3</td>
        <td class="stock">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to do this with jquery. I hope it is understood. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: I've answered below for you, have a check !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need :

```js
// First initialize the default variables, with your opening balance
var stockCount = 0;
var updatedStock = Number($(".opening.balance").html()) == "NaN" ? 0 : Number($(".opening.balance").html());
// For each "product", calculates the stock with the previous stock
$("tr.product").each(function(index) {
  stockCount = 0;
  
  // Number is used to convert string to number, so we can calculate
  var entry = Number($("td.entry", $(this)).html());
  var exit = Number($("td.exit", $(this)).html());

  entry = entry == "NaN" ? 0 : entry;
  exit = exit == "NaN" ? 0 : exit;

  var stock = updatedStock + entry - exit;
  updatedStock = stock;

  stockCount += stock;
  $("td.stock", $(this)).html(stock);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>producto</th>
        <th>entry</th>
        <th>exit</th>
        <th>stock</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr><td class="opening balance">10</td></tr>
    <tr class="product">
        <td class="info">TP031</td>
        <td class="entry">4</td>
        <td class="exit">0</td>

        <td class="stock"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
        <td class="info">SI0352</td>
        <td class="entry">0</td>
        <td class="exit">3</td>

        <td class="stock"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
        <td class="info">MP4012</td>
        <td class="entry">0</td>
        <td class="exit">3</td>

        <td class="stock"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Be careful, you've set an id to the second row.

You can associate a click event with a button to calculate :)

Hope I helped.

(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXVrNd)

Comment: excellent, it helps me a lot, thanks for the help, they are very friendly ..
saludos desde chile

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var iTotalStock = 0;
        $('#tabla tbody tr').find('td.stock').each(function () {


            iTotalStock = iTotalStock + parseInt($(this).text(), 10);

        });
        $('#total').val(iTotalStock)
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

   <table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>producto</th>
        <th>entry</th>
        <th>exit</th>
        <th>stock</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr><td class="opening balance">10</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="info">TP031</td>
        <td class="entry">4</td>
        <td class="exit">0</td>

        <td class="stock">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="info">SI0352</td>
        <td id="entry">0</td>
        <td class="exit">3</td>

        <td class="stock">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="info">MP4012</td>
        <td class="entry">0</td>
        <td class="exit">3</td>
        <td class="stock">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <br /><br />
      Total<input type="text" id="total"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to get the total of the stocks.

This can be achieve by adding all stocks. We need to use jquery `each` for it.

Following code will give the total stock count.

```
var stockTotal=0;

$(function(){
    $('.stock').each(function(){
        stockTotal= stockTotal+ parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    alert(stockTotal);
});
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cLxf02w/)

Hope this helps.

-Help :)